# Shortening multiple or conditions

Tags: r

Hope I'm not being extremely lazy here but I was wondering whether there was a way to shorten this condition

```
dataframe[holiday == 'Yes' & ( type == 1 | type == 2 | type == 3 ), ]
```

I think the syntax is wrong here, but what I'm trying to do is show all people that have been on a holiday and have chosen either type 1, 2 or 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lets say dataframe is df then it would be

```
df[(df$holiday == 'Yes') & (df$type %in% c(1, 2, 3)), ]
```

Comment: You've got an extra bracket there!

Comment: you could also use `with`

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong if `holiday` and `type` are columns of that `data.frame`: `[.data.frame` doesn't evaluate its contents within scope, meaning this doesn't make sense unless `holiday` and `type` are variables in the global environment. Instead I suspect you mean this:

```
dataframe[dataframe$holiday == 'Yes' & 
         (dataframe$type == 1 | dataframe$type == 2 | dataframe$type = 3),]
```

Rather than using mulitple OR statements, its much more concise to use `%in%`:

```
dataframe[dataframe$holiday == 'Yes' & dataframe$type %in% 1:3,]
```

However the `data.table` library DOES evaluate the column names in the scope of `data.table`, allowing you to go back to your original syntax:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(data.frame)
dt[holiday == 'Yes' & type %in% 1:3,]
```

Comment: Maybe he `attach(dataframe)`? it seems like many new R users do that as I saw it in many academic articles (seems like Profs like `attach` for some reason)

Comment: Wow I didn't know you could do that. Seems like a great way to get unintended side effects!

Comment: See [this guys](http://anson.ucdavis.edu/~hiwang/teaching/10fall/R_tutorial%201.pdf) tutorial for reference